# What do OrientDB's functions do when applied to the results of another function?

Tags: sql, orientdb

I am getting very strange behavior on `2.0-M2`. Consider the following against the `GratefulDeadConcerts` database:

#### Query 1

```
SELECT name, in('written_by') AS wrote FROM V WHERE type='artist'
```

This query returns a list of artists and the songs each has written; a majority of the rows have at least one song.

#### Query 2

Now try:

```
SELECT name, count(in('written_by')) AS num_wrote FROM V WHERE type='artist'
```

On my system (OSX Yosemite; Orient 2.0-M2), I see just one row:

```
name           num_wrote
---------------------------
Willie_Cobb    224
```

This seems wrong. But I tried to better understand. Perhaps the `count()` causes the `in()` to look at all written_by edges...

#### Query 3

```
SELECT name, in('written_by') FROM V WHERE type='artist' GROUP BY name
```

Produces results similar to the first query.

#### Query 4

Now try `count()`

```
SELECT name, count(in('written_by')) FROM V WHERE type='artist' GROUP BY name
```

Wrong path -- So try `LET` variables...

#### Query 5

```
SELECT name, $wblist, $wbcount FROM V 
LET $wblist  = in('written_by'), 
    $wbcount = count($wblist) 
WHERE type='artist'
```

Produces seemingly meaningless results:

[image: screen capture of query 5 results on orientdb studio]

You can see that the `$wblist` and `$wbcount` columns are inconsistent with one another, and the `$wbcount` values don't show any obvious progression like a cumulative result.

Note that the strange behavior is not limited to `count()`. For example, `first()` does similarly odd things.

Answer (score 1):

`count()`, like in RDBMS, computes the sum of all the records in only one value. For your purpose `.size()`seems the right method to call:

```
in('written_by').size()
```